# Travel on Short/Visit on Schengen Visa with separate tickets

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, return-tickets

I am travelling from Mumbai to Prague on a short term visa, that requires a return ticket. Is is ok if I buy 2 different tickets from 2 different airlines, one for going out and other to return.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a costlier?

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely fine. It’s quite common for people to book separate tickets now. As long as you can prove you’ll leave the Schengen area with a return ticket you should have no problems.